# Phalcon Model update not working

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

This is my model:

```
class Users extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $fname;
    public $lname;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $emailVerified;
    public $suspended;
}
```

And now I am going to `suspend` a user...

```
                $user = Users::findFirst(
                                    array(
                                        'conditions' => "email=:email:",
                                        'bind' => array(
                                            'email' => $context->request->getPost("email")
                                        ))
                                );
                $user->suspended = 1;
                $user->save();
```

and now here comes the problem, after I update the user data, the `suspended` field is set to `1` as expected but what is strange is that the `emailVerified` field is updated too. now both fields hold the value: `1`.

I have no idea how this is happening. I searched the internet but could not find similar issues. am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

This is mySQL log. I found the problem. the value that Phalcon query builder creates for `emailVerified` is wrapped in single quote. so it's a string and the field type is `bit`.

[image]

```
111 Query   

UPDATE `users` SET `fname` = 'user_fname', `lname` = 'user_lname', `email` = 'user_email', `emailVerified` = '0', `suspended` = 1 WHERE `id` = '3'

111 Quit
```

Comment: Do you have beforeValidation or beforeSave methods in your Users model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems with this a while ago too. It appeared that `bit` columns aren't supported in Phalcon. You should use `tinyint` instead.

I also found a [closed issue](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/10888) 'confirming' this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything wrong with your above code that result in the issue your seeing. I would recommend setting your database to dump all SQL quires and double check your database for default values and functions that might change the value inside the database it-self.

Comment: the value provided for `emailVerified` in the query is wrapped in single quote. I think this is the problem, but I have no idea how to fix it.